# How to display web scraped data in a pyqt window?

Tags: qt, beautifulsoup, pyqt4, python-3.4

I am trying to display a particular Premier League teams results in a PyQt window after a button is pressed. I have used BeautifulSoup to scrape the teams results from a webpage. At the moment when I click on the button, a new window opens however the results of the team are outputted into the python shell and not the PyQt window which is what I want to do.
Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

My code is shown below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *



class MyPopup(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    QTextBrowser.__init__(self)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
    self.cw = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
    self.btn1 = QPushButton("Chelsea", self.cw)
    self.btn1.setGeometry(QRect(50, 40, 100, 30))
    self.connect(self.btn1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.doit)
    self.w = None

  def doit(self):
    self.w = MyPopup()
    self.w.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
    self.w.show()
    url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/chelsea/results/'
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    for match in soup.select('table.table-stats tr.report'):
        team1 = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
        team2 = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
        score = match.abbr
        if not all((team1, team2, score)):
            continue
        print(team1.text, score.text, team2.text)

class App(QApplication):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    QApplication.__init__(self, *args)
    self.main = MainWindow()
    self.connect(self, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), self.byebye )
    self.main.show()

  def byebye( self ):
    self.exit(0)

def main(args):
  global app
  app = App(args)
  app.exec_()

sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```